# Data Migration Nexus 2 to dockerized nexus 3

Tags: docker, nexus

Is there a way of placing a hosted Nexus 2 in read-only mode so that users can write anything new to repos so that when using the upgrade agent to Migrate to a dockerized nexus 3 things dont get out of sync in case the dns transition to new dockerized Nexus isnt available right away.

I ask, even though we sent out a company wide email that this transition is happening, there are those people that forget and then push changes to old version and then we have issues with being out of sync.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer **yes**.

You can right click on a repository in NXRM2 and put it "Out of Service".  That will prevent use.
If you just want to prevent writes not reads as well, you can edit the configuration, "Deployment Policy" and make "Read Only".
I don't believe there's a mass way to make all repositories out of service or read only, you'd need to do one at a time.

However, it's also worth noting that the NXRM3 upgrade wizard accounts for this case and until you stop Syncronizing will move over anything new pushed to NXRM3.
If you're concerned despite this, note that the changes I noted above will move over to NXRM3 as well, so in order to use it, you'll need to manually undo them all on the NXRM3 side.